# Compile the GPU version of FFMPEG to OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, video, ffmpeg

When I try to use GPU 
FFMPEG on opencv by using a command like:

```
VideoCapture cap("rtsp link");

for(;;)
{
mat frame;
cap>>frame;
}
```

I don't see any output on nvidia-smi despite compiling the GPU version of FFMPEG.

I am trying to get FFMPEG to use GPU to improve the speed of my program. I got FFMPEG from cloning [this](https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git) and followed the steps [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg) to get it working.

I have validated the results using `nvidia-smi dmon -i 0` and have seen that `dec%` increases when I run the command `ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i test_video.mp4 test_output.mkv`.

I then compiled Opencv to use the GPU enabled FFMPEG, I check this by running getBuildInformation from opencv:

```
Video I/O: 
DC1394 1.x: NO 
DC1394 2.x: YES (ver 2.2.4) 
FFMPEG: YES 
codec: YES (ver 58.20.103) 
format: YES (ver 58.17.100) 
util: YES (ver 56.18.102) 
swscale: YES (ver 5.2.100) 
resample: NO 
gentoo-style: YES 
GStreamer: NO 
OpenNI: NO 
OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules: NO 
OpenNI2: NO 
PvAPI: NO 
GigEVisionSDK: NO 
UniCap: NO 
UniCap ucil: NO 
V4L/V4L2: NO/YES 
XIMEA: NO 
Xine: NO 
gPhoto2: NO
```

I cross-verify that I'm using the same ffmpeg (by checking the version numbers):

```
ffmpeg version N-91273-g67747c8 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 20160609
  configuration: --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
  libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
  libavcodec     58. 20.101 / 58. 20.101
  libavformat    58. 17.100 / 58. 17.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
  libavfilter     7. 25.100 /  7. 25.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
```

Please advise me on how I should compile OpenCV to use the GPU version of FFMPEG. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly FFmpeg related, but as an advise for you to be able to use hugely performant GPU capabilities through OpenCV API.

Assuming that you use OpenCV 3.x.x - you should use special OpenCV GPU Api for video decoding. Take a look on this example from official documentation:

- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/video_reader.cpp

Also, foreseeing the problems with compilation and running the code with modern OpenCV 3.4.1 and >=CUDA 9.0, read through my comment on OpenCV's issue tracker to overcome those:

- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10201#issuecomment-402453361

And also yes - it will give you huge speed-up on video decoding/reading. Absolutely worth trying.

Comment: How is https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/video_reader.cpp different from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/cudacodec/src/cuvid_video_source.cpp ? I understand that the former requires OpenGL support. I talk about the latter in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11834

Comment: I am using Cuda 8.0

Comment: The code you've posted in question is standard OpenCV capture. You need to use OpenCV GPU capture API. I've tried to answer that question about how to use GPU with OpenCV.

Comment: I got it working using nvcuvid, however it doesnt work for RTSP. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11834

Comment: @PavelShvetsov In the second link you shared, there is no /usr/local/cuda/samples/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/dynlink_nvcuvid.cpp in the directory. I am using cuda-10.2

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Sorry, I'm not sure about setup steps with current CUDA10+ versions. Also in recent OpenCV4.x+ `nvcuvid` support was dropped. So you have to perform additional research.