# Can't use OpenCV to decode video on GPU with cv2.CAP_FFMPEG

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get all frames of list of videos(lots of .mp4 videos) using OpenCV. In order to speed up the process I was thinking may be I can use FFMPEG with Nvidia Video Codec SDK to use hardware-accelerated decoding(I have T4 cards on my machine). My code is something like this:

```
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"]="video_codec;h264_cuvid"
import cv2

ret = cv2.VideoCapture("input.mp4", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
while True:
    x, y = ret.read()
    if x:
        continue
    break
```

but I get these errors when I run my script.

```
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-afu9cjzs/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (1086) open Could not find decoder 'h264_cuvid'
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-afu9cjzs/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (1109) open VIDEOIO/FFMPEG: Failed to initialize VideoCapture
```

My ffmpeg configs, `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg version N-102965-gf531a1a4e8 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvdec --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp --enable-shared --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  3.101 / 59.  3.101
  libavformat    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.103 /  8.  0.103
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

and `ffmpeg -hwaccels`:

```
ffmpeg version N-102965-gf531a1a4e8 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvdec --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp --enable-shared --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  3.101 / 59.  3.101
  libavformat    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.103 /  8.  0.103
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
Hardware acceleration methods:
cuda
```

OpenCV version `opencv-python==4.5.3.56`

Comment: You might have to compile opencv with that ffmpeg build: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984383/compile-the-gpu-version-of-ffmpeg-to-opencv

Comment: Could be possible that it is easier to get gstreamer nvidia backend running with opencv

Answer (score 0):

In my setup I had to build ffmpeg to enable cuvid support.

You can check if your ffmpeg supports cuvid:

```
# type this in terminal:
ffmpeg -decoders 2>/dev/null | grep h264_cuvid
# returns:
 V..... h264_cuvid           Nvidia CUVID H264 decoder (codec h264)
```

You also need some nvidia libs in your system:

```
# type this in terminal:
ldconfig -p 2>/dev/null | grep cuvid
# You should see something similar to below:
        libnvcuvid.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libnvcuvid.so.1
        libnvcuvid.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libnvcuvid.so
```